# apollo graphql: how to query union type fields

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following schema for my server:

```
const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type DeliveryType {
    delivery: String!
    deliveryStreetNumberId: String!
    pickupLocationId: String!
    storeId: String!
  }

  type PickupType {
    storeId: String!
  }

  union OrderType = DeliveryType | PickupType

  type Query { 
    getOrderType(userId: String!): OrderType
  }
```

And then I have the following query definitions on my FE:

```
export const GET_ORDER_TYPE = gql`
  query getOrderType($userId: String!) {
    getOrderType(userId: $userId) {
      delivery
      deliveryStreetNumberId
      pickupLocationId
      storeId
    }
  }
`;
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

> graphQLErrors: [
> {
> message: 'undefined: Cannot query field "delivery" on type "OrderType". Did you mean to use an inline fragment on
> "DeliveryType"?'
> },
> {
> message: 'undefined: Cannot query field "deliveryStreetNumberId" on type "OrderType". Did you mean to use an inline fragment on
> "DeliveryType"?'
> },
> {
> message: 'undefined: Cannot query field "pickupLocationId" on type "OrderType". Did you mean to use an inline fragment on
> "DeliveryType"?'
> },
> {
> message: 'undefined: Cannot query field "storeId" on type "OrderType". Did you mean to use an inline fragment on "DeliveryType"
> or "PickupType"?'
> } ]

I thought that I could query all the fields from the union and then get `null` where the field is not available?

Is there another way to do this, or what would be the conventional way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which type to get the non-common fields from. In your case:

```
query getOrderType($userId: String!) {
  getOrderType(userId: $userId) {
    on DeliveryType {
      delivery
      deliveryStreetNumberId
      pickupLocationId
    }
    storeId
  }
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/#querying-a-union)

Comment: Thanks, and also kudos for linking the relevant docs page, don't know how I missed it.